# Exe generated by PyInstaller fails quietly on a different machine

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I'm having trouble getting an exe generated by PyInstaller on one PC (PC-Good) working on another (PC-Bad).

- The exe is created on PC-Good, and executes as expected on PC-Good
- Both PCs are running Windows 10
- Issue occurs on PC-Bad upon calling most of the matplotlib.pyplot methods (such as subplots() or plot())
- Issue persists even when matplotlib is in non-interactive mode
- No error is reported upon failure. exe simply exits

  - even when matplotlib verbosity is changed to 'debug'
  - even when the problem statement is captured in try-exception

See below for code:

```
print('Start')
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("Import of matplotlib & pyplot successful")

plt.set_loglevel("debug")

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
print('list creation successful')

try:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 6))
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception.__class__.__name__ + ": ", + exception.message)
finally:
    print('run subplots() successful')

plt.scatter(x, y)
print('plot creation successful')
plt.savefig('saved_plot.png')
print('code complete')
```

Output on PC-Good:

```
Start
C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\bcht\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:623: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Import of matplotlib & pyplot successful
list creation successful
run subplots() successful
plot creation successful
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: ...
(and many more matplotlib DEBUG messages)
code complete
```

Output on PC-Bad:

```
Start
C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\bcht\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:623: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
Import of matplotlib & pyplot successful
list creation successful
```

Since I get no error output, I'm quite lost as to where to go next. Matplotlib documentation doesn't offer any additional tips on getting more granular debug messages for methods like plot or subplots. Has anyone else observed such an issue or know of a fix? Or does anyone know if there's a way to get Matplotlib to tell me more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue, which I can't call a fix yet due to the fact that neither PyInstaller nor MatPlotlib provides any debug message to further the investigation for rootcause. Nevertheless, it gets rid of the issue that I was seeing.

**TL;DR**

- Issue is due to incompatibility when using PyInstaller to generate executable with Python codes with matplotlib 3.1.3 and numpy 1.18.1. This incompatibility does not cause the python script itself to error out. This incompatibility does not produce any error message or symptoms that would point to itself, thus, making it difficult to rootcause.
- If anyone observes a frozen executable quitting silently without any error message. It's worthwhile to investigate whether this is due to library incompatibility. If the quitting occurs during execution of mpl methods, then look into numpy immediately.

**Now the TL:**
It started with a suspicion that the issue was due to virtual environment or conda meddling with the freezing process (they are not) so I used another computer to install a clean python (3.7.9), and matplotlib 3.1.3 which populated all its dependencies automatically (let's call this new environment "lean env" and the Source PC in the problem statement "full env"). I replicated the bundling/freezing process on lean env and everything works fine. At this point, I noticed that a number of libraries in the lean env are newer than the full env. So I upgraded them all on the full env, including:

numpy from 1.18.1 to 1.20.0
kiwisolver from 1.3.0 to 1.3.1

After this, the full env is also able to generate a bundle that works perfectly fine when run on both Source PC and Target PC. So the problem is likely to be the "silent" incompatibility between matplotlib 3.1.3 and one of those two.

To narrow things further, I reverted numpy to 1.18.1 in the full env and reproduced the old problem I saw. There it is.

The frustrating aspect of this is that neither numpy nor matplotlib generated any discernable error (nor Pyinstaller). In addition, matplotlib itself does not have any method to produce any useful verbose debug message to further the investigation. (I did turn on the log_level of matplotlib to debug, but only got some info indicating the fonts being used.) For this reason, I will not proceed any further to investigate. The workaround is sufficient for my use. If anyone else is interested, feel free to proceed by interrogating mpl. Neither will I conduct further interop between pyinstaller, matplotlib, and numpy. All I'll say is:

**Good: matplotlib==3.1.3, numpy==1.20.0, pyinstaller==3.6**

**Bad: matplotlib==3.1.3, numpy==1.18.1, pyinstaller==3.6**

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this.

1. Pyinstaller didn't include modules "completely" : pyinstaller tries to reduce size by including only those parts of modules which are used by your application. It might not have detected the use of some vital part of module and not included it. Try using pyinstaller in one directory mode. Then you will be able to see the module selected by pynstaller. If something is missing then next time you can specify to include that module.
2. Try putting checkpoints like `print("reached some function")` in your code for debugging purpose. It will make it easier to find where is the problem.
3. Also try to run the code in a normal python on target computer.

Comment: #1, it's perplexing that the same distro works on one computer but not the other. I would think the issue with module inclusion will persist across machines. But I will follow your advice and try to use hidden_imports (or others) to maximize the inclusion of Matplotlib related data and modules. If you know of a specific way to "literally dump the Matplotlib" into the distro, please let me know.
#2. I agree and have implemented it already. The comparison between good and bad prints is in the question post.
#3. The python code runs okay on the target computer.

Comment: Yes when in one foldet mode in pyinstaller, you can literally copy paste the module folder from your python directory to your app directory. Or atleast thats how i do it

Comment: That did not work either, unfortunately. I've dumped all files within matplotlib (inside my venv Lib/site-packages) inside the dist directory. Not working. I know matplotlib pulls in other libraries, too. So I dumped the entire content of site-packages inside the dist directory. Again, not working. It's questionable whether the Pyinstaller bootloader knows to import them even if I have "force-fed" the content. Any idea how I should instruct Pyinstaller bootloader to look in there?

Comment: Try to use the command:-
pyinstaller --hidden-import=first_module --hidden-import=second_module

Comment: --hidden-import can be used multiple times

Comment: But since you didn't get any import error, i would highly suggest you to put `print("reached here")` style checkpoints after every line

Comment: All good suggestions, however
- w.r.t. the hidden imports, I have indeed included all I could find that are relevant to matplotlib, one of which is "matplotlib.*" which should be a catch-all. In addition, I went further by using collect_data_files("matplotlib") in the "datas" option. Neither helped.

- if you read the python code in the problem statement carefully, you would notice that I have already embedded print statements after every single function call from the very beginning. Also note that the output indicates exactly where the statement starts to drop.